# Prevent Children from Overflowing Parent's padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a component that has several children inside. These children seem to be overflowing the parent's padding if the content is too large. See photo below [image: Overflowing padding]

All content should have ended at the crudely drawn dashed line at the bottom of the photo.

Here is an example of what my component looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';

function Video(){

   const data = {
       channel: 'Govana',
       name: 'Video Four',
       description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   }

    return(
    <VideoWrapper>
        
        <Wrapper>
        </Wrapper>
    
        <Info>
            <Title>{data.name}</Title>
            <ChannelName>{data.channel}</ChannelName>
            <Description>{data.description}</Description>
        </Info>      
        
    </VideoWrapper>
    )
}

const Title = styled.h2`
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
`

const Description = styled.p`
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.9rem;    
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
`

const ChannelName = styled.h3`
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
`

const VideoWrapper = styled.div`
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;500;700&display=swap');
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cbd5e0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 20px;    
    letter-spacing: .025em;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
`
const Info = styled.div`
    flex: 1 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: green;    
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
`

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    flex: 1 200px;      
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color:red;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
        
`
```

Any idea as to what I might be doing wrong/missing?
All help/guidance is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try add height or max height to parent element

Comment: @Khant I've tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: What about adding `width` or `height` attributes to the Info div?

Comment: @HarleyLang a height is already set.

Comment: I see the styled div `Info` has flex shrink/grow attributes but not width and height, have you tried adding width and height to that styled component? Perhaps try height 100%

Comment: I might be missing what you're trying to say but there's already a `height:100%;` on the `Info` styled component.